# Programmatically refresh layer usage information

Tags: c#, autocad

In AutoCAD, through the Layer Properties Manager UI, a user can refresh the usage information for layers in a drawing.  The information sometimes get stale when you have layers from xrefs.  In your code, when you access the `LayerTable` for a drawing, its records will not include those layers that it deems as unused (in the Layer Properties Manager UI grey status = unused, blue status = used).  In order for me to get to those layers, my program first needs to refresh the usage information.  Is there a way to do this through the .NET API, COM API, or the command line?

I'm also pursing an answer in parallel in the AutoCAD forums

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/Programmatically-refresh-layer-usage-information-NET/m-p/2794756

Comment: After further testing. I discovered that it's missing the layers if you are working through the Database but if you go through the Document then they will be there.  However, I would prefer to go through the Database because it is much quicker than opening the drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that one of the entities in the particular drawing was corrupt. When one of the users recreated the drawing (including re-adding some xrefs) and ran the program it worked just fine.  I also double checked the code and it was definitely hitting the correct layers this time.  I am however open to suggestions or solutions on how to detect corruption problems in AutoCAD drawings.